# Need to prevent site name from breaking to next line on smaller devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site at concrete.lifestylerevolutionstx.com, and for some reason the site name breaks to the next line, below the logo, at smaller screen sizes. Any ideas how can I force them to stay on the same line?

Comment: [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space)?

Comment: Also, don't point at "live" web sites. It's better to provide simple HTML (use something like placeholder.it for the images) and CSS reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @millimouse suggested in the comments, since your logo header is part text and part image, you should add `white-space: no-wrap;` to the container, in this case it's `.top-bar .name h1 a`. This will suppress line breaks within text.

Additionally, you should consider removing `overflow: hidden;` on your `nav` element with the class `.top-bar` and adding a `z-index` of at least 3 to your `section` element with the class `.top-bar-section`, so your hamburger button menu actually appears over your scrolling gallery for lower screen width (width <= 979px) displays.